# Motorola Triumph & HyperShell in Titanium Backup

Tags: titanium-backup, busybox, motorola-triumph

It would seem that Titanium Backup, everyone's favorite root backup tool (right?), does not particularly like the Motorola Triumph—or vice versa. I've been having problems with restoring apps (only the Manual, APK installer method works) and integrating system updates (it just hangs, and then the app it hung on is broken until I restore it from a backup).

My TiBU (5.4.0.2) main screen says that I have root, BusyBox 1.20.2-Stericson from system, and HyperShell—but then turns around and says "Fast/Auto app install: NO (HyperShell needed)". Whiskey Tango Foxtrot.

The BusyBox I have installed is the latest version, and I had the same problem when I was using the BusyBox 1.18.x build included in TiBU. I have also tested using both the stock and Umph v1.0 kernels.

*Why is everything on the Triumph so bloody buggy? I never had these problems on my old LG Optimus V.*

Comment: Interesting question - I have Titanium Backup that is failing to recognize my license key (yes I have a valid license and donated!) I am guessing its something to do with how the partitions are laid out. And each time, it refuses no matter how hard I try, the darn thing refuses to recognize it and treats it as a free version, as you say, Whiskey Tango Foxtrot! :D

Comment: Could you try manually mounting `/system` as writable and see if integrating system updates works then?

Comment: "/system mounted as rw!" — Remount // "Processing… \n Please wait" — Titanium Backup (for a long time, until force stopped) :-/ (I'm off now to fix Play Store so it works again.)

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the developer with as much details as you've got. Joel is very cooperative. There are some very special issues with some ROMs and devices -- but he cannot solve them without either buying all the devices available (not a real option) or good help from those using them (you in this case). I'd bet, once you've sent him the details, a fix is available within a week.

Comment: Is Joel someone I can reach by emailing the general Titanium Track support address? I never seem to get an answer through that channel.